# water not turning on for washer supply valves

Tags: plumbing, valve, washer

For some reason my hot and cold supply lines to my washer are not working.  My washer was not filling so thought it was the washer but after taking the hoses off no water through the valves.  I have a newer house 8 years old and have the 1/2 turn red and blue valves at the wall.  I turn them off and on and nothing.  I can see the valves open.  All other water connections are working.  I turned off the main valve that comes into my house and no help.  I live in Richmond Va and we had some very cold weather so maybe a pipe is frozen but would it really be hot and cold?   I tried to find the pipes in my basement and seems like they are all PVC not copper.

Also not sure if part of problem but in the laundry room I have a sink and it seems no cold water is coming out only hot.  It was working before I turned off the main though.

FYI they were working a couple days ago when I did laundry.

Any help greatly appreciated before I call a plumber.

Comment: Are the supply pipes to the valves that are not working in exterior walls? Are  they PVC or PEX?

Comment: Sounds like frozen, are the connections on an exterior wall?

Comment: Thanks so for for the questions.  They are PVC piping.  They are on an exterior wall but they run into my basement.  The utility room is nice and toasty.  I cant fully tell if I have the right pipes but they look like they are coming out from where the supply valve would be.  I heated them with a heat gun lightly for a couple minutes and nothing.   Temps have been in the 20's for about 4 days going above freezing today and 50's rest of the week.

Comment: its odd about the laundry room sink.  Unfortunately I knew hot water was working before I turned off main valve but did not try the cold.  Now only hot water works not a drop from the cold.  As an FYI those water lines are about 2-3  feet from each other.

Comment: If you turned off the main valve your laundry sink cold will be off, as with all the other cold water outlets in the house. Hot water may come out for a while by gravity pressure from the water heater, but don't let your water heater empty out very much before turning the main water back on - you don't want the water heater heating an empty tank.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the lines, I would say frozen. Sometimes if you can access them, you can tap on them lightly and see if there is a change in the sound from one section to another, follow the pipe all the way from the appliance as far as you can. It it sounds hollow in one section closer to the washer and more solid the other way, you have a blockage of some sort. Try to carefully heat the pipe where it sounds more solid close to the hollow section. You might also be able to "feel" the pipe for hot or cold sections. Usually of the wash basin and machine are close, they feed from the same pipe and if you have water at one and not the other, you have a blockage.